# Validating conditional pairs of props with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm struggling to understand how to validate that two props either exist or don't.

In other words, they are both optional, but if one exists, the other must also.

I don't quite understand how a conditional type would work in this scenario, in all the examples I've seen the condition is if the class extends another class or not, so how would that work here?

```js
interface DateInputProps {
  onDateChange: (date: Date) => void;
  date: any;
}

interface DateInputPropsNull {}

type SelectiveProps<T> = T extends _what?_
  ? DateInputPropsNull
  : DateInputProps;

class DateInput extends React.Component<
  SelectiveProps<_what?_>,
  DateInputState
> {

    render() {
        const {
          date = this.state.date,
          onDateChange = (date: any) => this.setState({ date })
        } = this.props;
        ...
    }

}
```

I would then expect to be able to do:

```js
<DateInput /> //No type error
<DateInput date="2011-01-05" onDateChange={(date)=> console.log(date)}/> //No type error
<DateInput date="2011-01-05" /> //Error - onDateChange is required
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
interface DateInputProps {
  onDateChange: (date: Date) => void;
  date: string;
}

interface DateInputPropsNull {
  onDateChange?: undefined,
  date?: undefined
}

type SelectiveProps = DateInputProps | DateInputPropsNull

class DateInput extends React.Component<SelectiveProps>
```

So if you pass one of the value you will get the type error. The only problem with this solution is that when you pass `undefined` to `date` or `onDateChange`, it will not give you the error.

```
<DateInput /> //No type error
<DateInput date="2011-01-05" onDateChange={(date)=> console.log(date)}/> //No type error
<DateInput date="2011-01-05" /> //Error - onDateChange is required
<DateInput date={undefined} onDateChange={undefined} /> // No type error
```

Comment: That works, and I can live with the undefined not causing a type error.
It seems like I should be able to "do it properly" I just don't quite understand how

Comment: @SJT Use `never` instead of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do it like this:

```
interface IDateInputProps {
  date?: any;
  onDateChange()?: void;
}

export class DateInput extends React.Component<IDateInputProps, DateInputState> {
  render() {
    const { date, onDateChange } = this.props;

    if ((!date && onDateChange) || (date && !onDateChange)) {
      throw new Error('"date" and "onDateChange" props must occur together");
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but I think that would do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, that works as a runtime test, but I'm looking for a way of type checking to use in the editor to get completion/error checking